# GPS Location Coordinaties in PHP

Tags: php

How can I write a code that gets the current location coordinates (LLA) in my web browser using PHP .

Is it possible by using GPS via HTTP or something like that ?

please help

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to use the brower's geolocation API, for example as shown [here](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_geolocation.asp).

Then, you simply pass the parameters to a PHP script using whatever method you like, a form, or a jQuery post.